# How to make Google reCaptcha mandatory or required?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, recaptcha

I have a contact form and I've added the reCAPTCHA v2 successfully but I can't make it a mandatory/required option. So currently if I click on the submit button it sends the message without even getting verified (without clicking on the "I'm not a robot") which makes it useless.

code:

> ```
> <?php
> $page_id = 4;
> $page_details = get_page_details($page_id);
> ini_set(sendmail_from, "");
> require ("class.phpmailer.php");
>
> $mail = new PHPMailer();
>
> if ($_POST["action"] == "sendmail_contact"){
>   $from = $_POST["email"];
>   $contact_data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from contact_info"));
>   $to = $contact_data["email"];
>   $check_dir = "contact_files/uploads/folder" . $_SESSION["UID_Contact"];
>   $results_array = array();
>   if (is_dir($check_dir)){
>       if ($handle = opendir($check_dir)){
>           while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE){
>               if ($file != "Thumbs.db" and $file != "." and $file != ".."){$results_array[] = $file;}}
> closedir($handle);}}
> if ($results_array[0] != ""){
>       $thumbpath1 = $results_array[0];
>       $mail->AddAttachment("$check_dir/$thumbpath1");}   
>   if ($results_array[1] != ""){
>       $thumbpath2 = $results_array[1];
>       $mail->AddAttachment("$check_dir/$thumbpath2");}
>   if ($results_array[2] != ""){
>       $thumbpath3 = $results_array[2];
>       $mail->AddAttachment("$check_dir/$thumbpath3");}
>   if ($results_array[3] != ""){
>       $thumbpath4 = $results_array[3];
>       $mail->AddAttachment("$check_dir/$thumbpath4");}
>   $subject = 'Contact Us Page';
>   $Message = "";
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>IP : </strong> ' . $ip_address . '</font><br /><br />';
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Country : </strong> ' . $country . '</font><br /><br />';
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Heard from : </strong> ' . $_POST["where"] . '</font><br /><br /><br />';
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Name : </strong> ' . ucfirst($_POST["name"]) . '</font><br /><br />';
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>E-mail : </strong> ' . $_POST["email"] . '</font><br /><br />';
>   $Message.= '<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Message : </strong> ' . $_POST["details"] . '</font><br /><br />';
>   $Message1.= $Message;
>   $mail->From = $from;
>   $mail->FromName = $from;
>   $mail->AddAddress($to);
>   $mail->IsHTML(true);
>   $mail->Subject = $subject;
>   $mail->Body = $Message1;
>   $mail->Send();
>   header("location: $site_url/contact-thank-you");}
> ?>
> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var $j_123 = jQuery.noConflict();
> $j_123(document).ready(function() {
>     var validator = $j_123("#contactusfrm").validate({
>         rules: {
>             name: "required",
>             email: {required: true,email: true },
>             details: "required"
>         },
>         messages: {
>             name: "<span class=\"alert_contact\">required</span>",
>             email: {required: "<span class=\"alert_contact\">required</span>",email: "<span class=\"alert_contact\">invalid</span>" },
>             details: "<span class=\"alert_contact\">required</span>"
>         }
>     });
> }); < /script> 
>
> <script src='google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <div class="content">
>
> <form id="contactusfrm" name="contactusfrm" method="post" action="url/contact">
> <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendmail_contact"/>
>
> Your Name *<input name="name" type="text" class="textbox" id="name" title="Name"/>
>
> Your Email *<input name="email" type="text" class="textbox" id="email" title="Email"/>
>
> How did you hear about us?<select name="where" class="dropdown" id="where" title="How did you hear about us">
> <option value="-">Click to Choose...</option>
> <option value="Google Search"> Google Search </option>
> <option value="Social Media"> Social Media </option>
> <option value="Blog"> Blog </option>
> <option value="Recommendation"> Recommendation </option>
> <option value="Advertisement"> Advertisement </option>
> <option value="Forum"> Forum </option>
> <option value="Other"> Other </option>
> </select>
>
> Your Message *<br/><textarea name="details" class="textarea" id="details" title="Message"></textarea>
>
> <div id="fileuploader"><div class="ajax-file-upload">UPLOAD FILE</div></div>
> <script  type="text/javascript">
> var $jj = jQuery.noConflict();
> $jj(document).ready(function(){
> $jj("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
> url:"<?php
> echo $site_url ?>/contact_files/upload.php",  
> fileName:"myfile",
> multiple:true,
> returnType:"json",
> showDelete:true,
> deleteCallback:function(data, pd){
> for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
> $jj.post("<?php
> echo $site_url ?>/contact_files/delete.php",{op:"delete",name: data[i]},
> function(resp,textStatus, jqXHR){});}}});});
> </script>
>
> <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-----key----"></div>
>
> <div class="bot-cont"><button name="submit_button" type="submit" class="submit_button" value="SUBMIT MESSAGE">SUBMIT MESSAGE</button></div>
>
> </form>
> </div>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="url/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
>
> </body>
> ```

Also, in my form when the user submits the message successfully he/she will be redirected to another page (Thank You page) so I won't be needing any "success" captcha message.

I'll only be needing an error message with the "required" text (like the ones I have already for the other fields) only when the user tries to submit without checking the "I'm not a robot".

Does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Comment: You clearly haven't taken a moment to look at how recaptcha works. Here's a link: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php ; you should delete the question.

Comment: What I want to use is reCAPTCHA v2 and the link you gave I think is for  the old reCAPTCHA v1 which is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the "g-recaptcha-response" variable when the target is processed.  Look at this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
      //your site secret key
      $secret = '9LuDh9kyetYYYYdT0jsVckScsH8Ks3KA';
      //get verify response data
      $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
      $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
      if($responseData->success):
        //contact form submission code
        $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
        $email = !empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';
        $message = !empty($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:'';

        $to = 'contact@codexworld.com';
        $subject = 'New contact form have been submitted';
        $htmlContent = "
            <h1>Contact request details</h1>
            <p><b>Name: </b>".$name."</p>
            <p><b>Email: </b>".$email."</p>
            <p><b>Message: </b>".$message."</p>
        ";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From:'.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
        //send email
        @mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

        $succMsg = 'Your contact request have submitted successfully.';
      else:
        $errMsg = 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
      endif;
  else:
    $errMsg = 'Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.';
  endif;
else:
  $errMsg = '';
  $succMsg = '';
endif;
```

The above example ensures that the g-recaptcha-response was passed, checks the response, and then if the captcha check did not succeed, shows a verification error.  Use this example to modify your code to check for the successful recaptcha usage.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the code, I've tried it but unfortunately this doesn't work. The code is very similar to the others I have tried before. I'm starting to think that the problem might be related to something else from my code that doesn't allow the recaptcha to work properly. I can't seem to figure out what.